# build expression of variable length (macro's in R?)

Tags: r, macros

I am building an `R` function that requires the size of an `expression` to vary according to the size of another variable.

The sequence of the expressions elements is as follows:

```
1/  1
2/ "Xts_filled[(locNAs[n] - 1),]"
3/ "Xts_filled[(locNAs[n] - 2),]"
4/ "Xts_filled[(locNAs[n] - 3),]" 
...
```

The expression has a regular pattern, with only the number after the minus changing as each element is added: it seems the perfect candidate for some sort of `macro`.

Is this possible in `R`?

I've hacked it using a `for` loop and the `eval(parse(text = ___))` idiom as follows:

```
buildExpr <- function(ARorder){
    callList <- list("1", "Xts_filled[(locNAs[n] - 1),]")
    if(ARorder - 1) {
        for(j in 2:ARorder) {
            callList <- c(callList, paste0("Xts_filled[(locNAs[n] -", j, "),]"))
        }
    }
    callExpr <- paste0("c(", paste(callList, collapse = ","), ")")
}
```

Which i put to work via `eval(parse(text = buildExpr(3)))`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: why bother with `eval(parse`?  why not just call it directly?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I need the object to evaluate to something like `c(1, 0.5, 0.25)`. Doing it this way got it to _work_ -- though i'm not sure it's the _best_ way.

Comment: see Hong Ooi's answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it directly.

```
out <- c(1, sapply(1:3, function(i) Xts_filled[locNAs[n] - i, ]))
```

If `Xts_filled[locNAs[n], ]` is 1, then this simplifies to

```
out <- sapply(0:3, function(i) Xts_filled[locNAs[n] - i, ])
```

Comment: +1, accepted. Thanks, very neat solution. For some reason it didn't occur to me to just evaluate and pass the result. I'm still interested in the `macro` question -- are they needed / useful in R?